# Fatal Error caused from failed upgrade - restore - CS Cart 4.2.4 > 4.3.1

Tags: cs-cart

I have recently upgraded my CS Cart website from 4.2.4 to 4.3.1

We have a custom theme installed so encountered a few issues that we didnt have time to address immediatley - so as per instruction, re ran the restore.

Now we have the following fatal error and I don't really know where to start. I am not much of a dev, but can follow instruction and am quite technically minded.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Ha might of helped if I'd put the error on.  Its this

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function assign() on a non-object in /home/digitalsaveadmin/public_html/app/addons/seo/controllers/frontend/init.post.php on line 19

Also, when I try to clear cache using ?cc I get this

Message
Storage: undefined storage type - assets
Error at
app/Tygh/Storage.php, line: 45
Backtrace
File: app/functions/fn.common.php
Line: 3822
Function: instance
File: app/functions/fn.init.php
Line: 740
Function: fn_clear_cache
File: app/functions/fn.init.php
Line: 940
Function: fn_check_cache
File: init.php
Line: 132
Function: fn_init
File: index.php
Line: 24
Function: require

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very interesting issue. I think the fastest way to resolve it, to contact the official CS-Cart Support Team. If you have a legal license, you have support credits, ask the team to resolve the issue will be free.

Comment: Hi ISTI

I actually managed to solve the issue myself.

FYI, CS Cart Support isnt free, you get a limited number of free support credits when you originally purchase cart, but additional credits much be purchased.  And the support takes a long time to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the assets issue please open the config.local.php file in the root directory and replace:

```
'custom_files' => array(
    'dir' => & $config['dir']['var'],
    'prefix' => 'custom_files'
)
```

with

```
'custom_files' => array(
    'dir' => & $config['dir']['var'],
    'prefix' => 'custom_files'
),
'assets' => array(
    'dir' => & $config['dir']['cache_misc'],
    'prefix' => 'assets',
    'cdn' => true
),
```